# Input voltage range of amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I had to design a circuit to work as an inverting amplifier.

The circuit is as shown below, and in order to obtain Gain 5, input resistance of 30kΩ, R6 has to be a potentiometer of 100kΩ and the op-amp is the uA741C, the resistors used are:

R1=30kΩ

R2=150kΩ

R3=10Ω

R4=100Ω

R5=1000Ω

R6above=1236Ω

R6below=98763Ω

[image]

Now I´m asked to find and justify what the input voltage range will be, and the maximum frequency the amplifier can work at.

Any ideas on how I should proceed or what the answer is?

I thought that this parameters would depend only on the op-amp used, and therefore the maximum voltage range and frequency of the circuit should be the same of those of the op-amp.

Comment: Look at the open loop gain graph of the uA741 and ask yourself if you wanted a closed loop gain of 5, what's the maximum frequency that this gain can be sustained.

Comment: Then say if the output range of +/-15 V is reduced to +/-12 with a 10k load and a gain of 5 what is the input range?  Hey Andy did you see they still sell 741's in metal cans for $22.50? or about ten quid.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 then if the op-amp is powered with +/- 15V, the output can range from +/-12V and if our gain is 5, the input voltage range shoud be around +/- 2,4V?

Comment: @Andyaka so 20·log(5)=13.97, if I look at the "Open-Loop Large-Signal Differential Voltage Amplification vs Frequency" graph, the maximum frequency should be around 200kHz?

Comment: you got it.. just remember to check input and output assumptions  for V.

Answer (score 0):

The lousy old (52 years old) 741 opamp has slew-rate output limiting above 9kHz. With a plus and minus 15V supply its datasheet shows an output no higher than plus and minus 6V at 20kHz, because its poor slewing converts a sinewave into a triangle-wave. At 200kHz its output is less than only 1V peak.

Comment: Then I should specify that the maximum frequency of operation will vary depending on the output voltage we want to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody uses an opamp that has trouble above 9kHz due to a poor slew rate, at 200kHz.
If you want 200kHz then select an opamp that works well at 200kHz.

Look at the difference on their datasheets of an old 741 opamp and a new audio opamp:
[image]